# Protractor - Firefox not reloading pages on browser.get(url)

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm writing some Protractor tests, but I'm running into trouble. When running the tests on Chrome, my tests all pass. When I run the tests on Firefox though, I see that the page is not re-loading between tests. (This messes up the state of the page and causes tests to fail.)

A workaround I'm using right now is to refresh after I 'get' the page, but this is dumb.

Here's my beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  browser.get('#/page');

  // I need this to get my Firefox tests to work
  browser.navigate().refresh();


});
```

What can I do to handle this better?

If I have to refresh the page each time, is there a clause like `if(firefox)` I can use?

I'm running Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.1) successfully, and Firefox 28.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) is giving me trouble.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to ignore synchronization? Is protractor not loading the page when you call browser.get()?

Comment: @Andres and OP: Thanks for the `ignoreSynchronization` extra line pointer. I suspect he OP added this line as a suggested fix to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/954#issuecomment-50873654). I know I did and later forgot to remove it and ended up with the same behaviour as the OP. Removing it makes it all merry.

Answer (score 0):

With synchronization off, all protractor does on a browser.get(url) is `driver.get(destination);`, so it's entirely up to the browser to determine how it wants to load the url. 
On the other hand, with synchronization on, protractor first loads a blank page before renavigating to the intended url.

In addition, for firefox, reloading the same angular url on localhost does not reload the page, whereas it does for chrome. Try it: go to an angular app on localhost, enter something in and load the url again. For chrome, this will clear what you entered, but for firefox, it will not.

Turn on synchronization like @AndresD said if your app is Angular